# Unexpected behavior of tuple boolean evaluation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63726/iterative-binary-search/63758#63758) and attempting to write a recursive function using the tuple boolean evaluation syntax (`(a,b)[bool]`).  My function is as follows (with some helpful prints):

```
def b(A,k,n):
 m=len(A)/2
 print "A: ", A
 print "m: ", m
 print "n: ", n
 print "A[m]", A[m]
 if A[m]==k:return m+n
 # return (m+n,(b(A[m:],k,m+n),b(A[:m],k,n))[A[m]<k])[A[m]!=k]
 return m+n if A[m]==k else (b(A[:m],k,n) if A[m]>k else b(A[m:],k,m+n))
```

Arguments `A`, `k`, and `n` are the input list to search, the key, and the index in the original `A`  which a sublist starts at.  `m` is the middle entry of the list.  If I search `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` for `6`, I would expect to see the following output

```
A:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
m:  3
n:  0
A[m] 4
A:  [4, 5, 6, 7]
m:  2
n:  3
A[m] 6
```

The correct output and result are produced with the non-commented return statement. However, when I attempt to use the commented return statement (which should be equivalent), I receive a recursion depth error.

Moreover, if I replace one of the recursive calls with a determinate value, then search for a value on the edge, it functions as expected.  For example, searching for `6` in `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` works correctly if my `return` statement is:

```
return (m+n,(b(A[m:],k,m+n),"anyValue")[A[m]>k])[A[m]!=k]
```

`"anyValue"` is never returned by my conditional in this case, so why does it matter what value I put in there?

**Why do these two statements evaluate differently?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
thing() if condition else other_thing()
```

only one of `thing()` and `other_thing()` is evaluated. The one that isn't returned doesn't get evaluated at all, so you can do things like

```
base_case_value if base_case_condition else continue_recursing()
```

and the recursion will stop at the base case.

When you do

```
(continue_recursing(), base_case_value)[base_case_condition]
```

Python needs to build the tuple before it can be indexed, so both `base_case_value` and `continue_recursing()` are evaluated no matter what. Your function doesn't stop when it hits the base case.

Comment: So what you're saying is that what I'm attempting is impossible with the tuple syntax?

Comment: @wnnmaw: Yup. While in theory, you could build a tuple of lambdas, pick one, and execute it, it'd be way longer.

Comment: @wnnmaw - the tuple method calculates both sides on an if/else clause and then discards one of them. It will never be faster than an if/else and it is potentially disasterous.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the two statements aren't equivalent. In the working "if" case, you only call `b` once per round. In the commented out "tuple boolean" case, you evaluate both `b` conditions before selecting which one to use with the boolean selector. Since `b` is recursive, and you always run the "bad" non terminating side along with the "good" terminating side, you get max recursion error.